# Building a new Xamarin.Forms project fails

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a new Xamarin.Forms project using Xamarin Studio (6.1.1 build 15. macOS v10.12).
I get a solution with 3 projects. One shared, one for iOS and one for Android. Everything build except the Android one. It fails when trying to compile the resources, specifically the styles file.

The following errors appear:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
```

I tried to remove all Android support related libraries and Xamarin.Forms itself and add them again with NuGet. But that didn't help.
The Xamarin.Forms version I'm using is 2.3.2.127.

Maybe someone can help me out here?

Edit:
This is the file where the errors occurs. I didn't change anything. This is what Xamarin generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I also removed all packages and re-added Xamarin.Forms. It automatically adds the required support packages. But the error still occurs.

Comment: How are you defining these resources in your `styles.xml`? Can you please post relevant code showing these items? Most of these errors come from the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/ packages. Make sure they are defined in your `Resources.designer.cs` file.

Comment: You need the support libraries as Xamarin.Forms uses them. May sound daft but have you tried a rebuild all? These are standard Android resources and sometimes they don't get pulled in first time so you need to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading `android_m2repository_r29.zip` repository from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/ with instruction given in same.